# Generic function adding entities to tables - Entity Framework 6 and C#

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, asp.net-mvc-4

I am trying to make a generic function which would help to avoid a repetition in my code. The function has to be generic with general type T (and perhaps T2) as has to refer to different fields in tables being created. I don't know if it's possible, though.

Let's say I have following entities to add to a database:

```
List<Type_1> entities_1 = new List<Type_1>()
{
    new Type_1{Field1="<Value of field 1",Field2="Value of Field 2", ...},
    new Type_1{Field1="<Value of field 1",Field2="Value of Field 2", ...},
    ...
    new Type_1{Field1="<Value of field 1",Field2="Value of Field 2", ...},
};
entities_1.ForEach(e => dbContext.Types_1.Add(e));
dbContext.SaveChanges();
entities_1 = null;

List<Type_2> entities_2 = new List<Type_2>()
{
    new Type_2{Field1="<Value of field 1",Field2="Value of Field 2", ...},
    new Type_2{Field1="<Value of field 1",Field2="Value of Field 2", ...},
    ...
    new Type_2{Field1="<Value of field 1",Field2="Value of Field 2", ...},
};
entities_2.ForEach(e => dbContext.Types_2.Add(e));
dbContext.SaveChanges();
entities_2 = null;

etc.
```

Is it possible to make a function with parameters: `List<T1>` and `dbContext` referring to `T2`, a function that would handle creating different tables? Perhaps that would require to parametrize those `Type_(n)` and `Types_(n)`. I tried something below but compiler does not accept it and points at T2:

```
private void addEntitiesToDbContext<T1,T2>(List<T1> ent, MyTypeContext dbContext)
{
    ent.ForEach(e => dbContext.T2.Add(e));
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Thanks




EDIT:

---

I feel like I've got to apologise for taking space in the comment section -.-

I have just realised what [C Bauer](https://stackoverflow.com/users/82333/c-bauer) said regarding the **Repository Pattern**. This is  If someone is also interested in this design, here's a very good link I recommend: [Repository Pattern Explained](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/615499/Models-POCO-Entity-Framework-and-Data-Patterns][1]). There's also a question regarding the Repository Pattern design [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26541819/how-to-retrieve-related-data-in-repository-pattern). Good luck.

PS. Another very good source on [Repository Pattern](http://www.codeguru.com/csharp/.net/net_asp/mvc/using-the-repository-pattern-with-asp.net-mvc-and-entity-framework.htm)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I hope those will help you.

```
public interface IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
}

public abstract class RepositoryBase<TEntity> : IRepository<TEntity>
    where TEntity : class
{
    private DbContext dbContext;

    private DbSet<TEntity> dbSet;

    public IQueryable<TEntity> All
    {
        get
        {
            return dbSet;
        }
    }

    public void InsertOrUpdate(TEntity entity)
    {
    }
}

public class Repository<T> : RepositoryBase<T>
    where T : class
{
    public Repository(DbContext context)
    {
        DbContext = context;
        DbSet = context.Set<T>();
    }
}
```

Comment: Hello Tau. I don't know why you were given mark down, so I am giving you mark up. Your solution is really advance. Although I understand concept of abstract classes, it's still hard to follow. I think I need more time for it and will try to crack it as soon as I can. Thanks for your time :)

Comment: @Ziko - Repository is a design pattern, which is rather advanced but should fulfill your needs 100%. When you are using the repository, type `Repository<EntityType> entityTypeRepository = new Repository<EntityType>();` where entitytype is the entity you are trying to perform CRUD operations on. Though normally your repository implementation would expose SubmitChanges or SaveChanges.

Comment: Hi. I took some tutorials to understand the example here. It's ok now but still need to ask two questions regarding the example. * Why RepositoryBase<TEntity> inherits from IRepository<TEntity>? My guess is that an Interface provides constraints that is reference type here. Also, interfaces do not allow for implementations of fields. * In Repository<T>, I don't understand the typing: `DbContext = context; DbSet = context.Set<T>();`
Shouldn't that be: `DbContext dbContext = context; DbSet<T> DbSet = context.Set<T>();` Thanks.

Comment: There's a slight mistake in the code above: `DbContext = ...` should be `dbContext = ...` as well as `DbSet = ` into `dbSet = ` because the fields are defined as such! In ehe comment above I asked for the reason of that. Now I have realised it is author's mistake!

Answer (score 0):

I can't think why this wouldn't work:

1)Create a common base class (or interface), call it BaseEntity, which all your entities derive from.

2)Add this to your context class:

```
IDbSet<BaseEntity> Entitys { get; set; }
```

3)Have your Add method take a list of BaseEntity's

```
private void addEntitiesToDbContext(List<BaseEntity> ent, MyTypeContext dbContext)
{
    ent.ForEach(e => dbContext.Entitys.Add(e));
    dbContext.SaveChanges();
}
```

Comment: Well, it says: `'X.X.dbContext' does not contain a definition for 'T2' and no extension method 'T2' accepting a first argument of type 'X.X.dbContext' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)`. Besically it says dbContext has no knowledge of T2 :/     I will try what you have suggested but I am beginner at c# so it may be still overwhelming :p I hope it will not :p